# Positioning a div element to match body background

Tags: html, css, position

I have the following code (screenshot: http://hi-tek.si/1.png):

```
<body style="margin:0px;
             padding:0px;
             background:url('bg_circles_top.png') no-repeat;
             background-position:-webkit-calc(50% - 34px) 0%;
             height:100%">
</body>
```

But now I want to add a div element that matches the body's background. The div should be left aligned to the start of the first "empty circle" and right aligned to the end of the second "empty circle" (screenshot: http://hi-tek.si/2.png):

[image: Background image with circles]

The problem is, that I don't know how to do that, because when zoomed page in/out it all messed up.

Comment: "because when zoomed page in/out it all messed up" - ???

Comment: I tried to set the size of div element by setting margin-left and margin-right. But when I zoom page out (Ctrl -) the div stays the same, but background is getting smaller.

Comment: Now this seems to be a strange use-case. Are you sure you should concentrate on zooming behaviour?